# Trying to hide my API key breaks my URL. Anyone know why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api-key

I'm new to javascript and trying to follow a Udemy tutorial and upload the code to github along the way. I need to hide an API key used in a URL that looks like the following:

`https://api.darksky.net/forecast/api-key-here/37.8267,-122.4233`

I created a .env file that contains a single line `API_KEY=my-key-of-numbers-here`

My entire code looks like this:

```html
const request = require('request');
require('dotenv').config();

const api_key = process.env.API_KEY;

const url = 'https://api.darksky.net/forecast/${api_key}/37.8267,-122.4233';

request({ url: url }, (error, response) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(response.body);
    console.log(data.currently);
});
```

When I run `node app.js` in the terminal I get back undefined. However, if I use the actual key everything works fine, but I obviously can't make the key public. How can I fix this?

Comment: Your code looks fine so I'll ask some questions. Have you installed dotenv?

Comment: Yes. Definitely installed it.

Comment: try `\`` instead `'`

Comment: Omg. Thank you that was it! I feel dumb.

Answer (score 1):

> try `` ` `` instead `'` – Estradiaz

Per the comment by @Estradiaz. I was using an apostrophe `'` around the URL instead of backticks `` ` ``. Solved.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have dotenv installed?

try `npm install dotenv` in the terminal.

Comment: Yes. I definitely typed `npm i dotenv` into the terminal. And when I look at `package.json` file it is definitely there. Version 8.2.0